# Having difficulty getting Javascript form to validate

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Been looking for an answer for hours now and I still haven't come up with a solution. I've tried looking for similar question, but none have helped, really.

So basically, what doesn't work is that the form submits without any error messages even if there are mistakes on the form. Basically, I could leave the name field empty and the form will still submit once I press the button. Hope this made sense. Any help is appreciated

Code:

```
function validateFinale()
{
  var emailOne = document.getElementById("em1").value;
  var emailTwo = document.getElementById("em2").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("name1").value;

  if (compare())
  {
    if (name, 'Please enter name'))
    {
      if (validEmail(getElementById('em1'), 'Email invalid'))
      {
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function validName(elem, helpmsg) {
  if (elem.value.length == 0) {
    alert(helpmsg);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function validEmail(elem, msg) {
  var wrongem = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]+$/;

  if (elem.value.match(wrongem)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert(msg);
    return false;
  }
}

function compare() {
  if (emailOne != emailTwo) {
    alert("Emails not the same");
    submitOk = "false";

    Document.getElementById("em1").value = " ";
    Document.getElementById("em2").value = " ";
    Document.getElementById("em1").focus();
  } else {
    alert("form complete, thank you");
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aj240/qgmt5yr8/

Comment: You've got at least two completely different classes of errors there. You really need to open up your JavaScript console and do some debugging yourself. Look at the error messages you get. Use Google to help you understand them.

Comment: compare() does not return a value.

Comment: There's several nonsensical and/or syntax errors in how this code is written. Take @Quentin's advice and learn how to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

you made syntax mistake, first you declare emailOne as local variable, than try reach it in global scope. You should declare variables emailOne and emailTwo in global scope.

```
var emailOne;
var emailTwo; 
function validateFinale()
{
 emailOne = document.getElementById("em1").value;
 emailTwo = document.getElementById("em2").value;
 var name = document.getElementById("name1").value;
```

One gold tip, try press F12 in your browser and all errors messages would appear in console.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q4xo1u7y/ there is working jsfiddle. I a little change how is declared validateFinale function, because jsFiffdle put all javascript in function onload. So I simple attach it to global object window.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `required  ="true"` in the input elems:

```
<input type="text" required ="true"...
```

Also, if you set `type="email"` in the e-mail field it will ask for an e-mail address (not at all, though, it just will accept anything with an "@")

And the code `validName(getElementById('name1'), ...)` should be `validName(getElementById('name1').value, ...)`, or else you'll get all the HTML element